# Get categories in custom post wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post `Download` and this custom post has a taxonomy naming `category`. And i have 4 type of category in this `category` taxonomy.I want to retrieve a list of these four categories.

### My format tree :

```
downloads(post type)
    |--- category (taxonomy)
             |---- cat1
             |---- cat2
             |---- cat3
             |---- cat4
```

I want a list of these 4 categories.

i have tried `get_object_taxonomies()` and `get_terms()` but it's not working

Comment: did you assign any post to any category?

Answer (score 0):

The following line will retrieve a list of objects related to existing categories for your custom post type:

```
<?php $categories = get_categories(array('type' => 'download', 'hide_empty' => 0)); ?>
```

Printing the names of all available categories:

```
<?php
foreach ($categories in $category) {
    echo $category->name;
}
```

For a full list of parameters take a look at [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)